# how to create an experience / level up system?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a DnD Character Creation program, and I've gotten myself stuck at the "Experience / Level" area. What I want is for every 1000 experience, the level to go up (so 0 to 999 is level 0,

So, I've used the following code to get where I am, but it doesn't change the label (lblLevel) to 1 when experience (txtExperience) is changed to 1000 (or 2 when experience is changed to 2000).

```
  Private Sub txtExperience_textChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtExperience.TextChanged
    If txtExperience.Text = letters Then
        lblLevel.Text = "0"
    ElseIf txtExperience.Text >= 10000 Then
        lblLevel.Text = "Maxed"
    End If
    Select Case txtExperience.Text
        Case Is <= "999"
            lblLevel.Text = "0"
        Case "1000" To "1999"
            lblLevel.Text = "1"
        Case "2000" To "2999"
            lblLevel.Text = "2"
        Case "3000" To "3999"
            lblLevel.Text = "3"
        Case "4000" To "4999"
            lblLevel.Text = "4"
        Case "5000" To "5999"
            lblLevel.Text = "5"
        Case "6000" To "6999"
            lblLevel.Text = "6"
        Case "7000" To "7999"
            lblLevel.Text = "7"
        Case "8000" To "8999"
            lblLevel.Text = "8"
        Case "9000" To "9999"
            lblLevel.Text = "9"
    End Select


End Sub
```

I'll be honest, I'm not sure if I'm using Select Case ... correctly, and when I tried using an If Statement (and Else If in place each of the Case ... to ...) it wouldn't work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Strings are not numbers.  "9" will evaluate as greater than "1000".  Turn on Option Strict and use numbers (integers)

Comment: Text is text. You can't compare it to numbers. Parse the text first with `Integer.Parse()` or `Integer.TryParse()` and you'll get a number that you can compare against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify that even further. Using basic math you can get rid of the long `Select Case` statement:

```
Dim Experience As Integer = 0
If Integer.TryParse(txtExperience.Text, Experience) = True Then
    If Experience >= 10000 Then
        lblLevel.Text = "Maxed"
        Return
    End If

    lblLevel.Text = Math.Floor(Experience / 1000).ToString()
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Input must be a whole number between 0 and 10000", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Here's an online test of my code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VtGFLx

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `integer` and `string`

```
Select Case Integer.Parse(txtExperience.Text)
        Case Is <= 999
            lblLevel.Text = 0
        Case 1000 To 1999
            lblLevel.Text = 1
        Case 2000 To 2999
            lblLevel.Text = 2
        Case 3000 To 3999
            lblLevel.Text = 3
        Case 4000 To 4999
            lblLevel.Text = 4
        Case 5000 To 5999
            lblLevel.Text = 5
        Case 6000 To 6999
            lblLevel.Text = 6
        Case 7000 To 7999
            lblLevel.Text = 7
        Case 8000 To 8999
            lblLevel.Text = 8
        Case 9000 To 9999
            lblLevel.Text = 9
    End Select
```

Comment: Ah, I see! so the quote marks were the issue! Thank you!